# Parse XML file in Safari iOS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, ios, safari

**How can I parse a xml file in iPad/iPod browser(is it called Safari iOS?) using Javascript?**

I know this works for Opera but what about Safari?

```
xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
xmlDoc.load('myXMLFIle.xml');
```

Comment: "...but what about Safari?" Are you asking if the code you showed works in Safari, or what to do in Safari? If the former, did you try it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var ParsedXMLDoc = ( new window.DOMParser() ).parseFromString( XMLContent, MIMEType );
```

The code above works for me in Safari on the Mac, I assume it is valid on iOS.

I think MIMEType may be optional, and you may need to ensure the XML prologue is present on your XML.

Given your example, you'll need to read the file you represent as "myXMLFIle.xml" into the `XMLContent` variable I show.